# How to get test GCM tokens?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, automated-tests, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have implemented a gateway service and push manager services to send push messages to GCM.
Now we want to do some automated testing.

How we can test GCM tokens?

We can get some tokens from real devices and after sometime they might expire and tests will fail. To test positive and negative scenarios we need known valid and invalid GCM tokens.

Any help guys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I may have misunderstood the question, thinking that you were asking how to test registration tokens.

If by test GCM tokens you mean the registration tokens, it is commonly generated upon app installation. With that said, you don't only receive them when using devices, you can also get one when using an emulator (I for one use it all the time for testing).

For valid, this one is pretty simple. First token you het upon installation should be good.

For invalid tokens, I think anything that isn't a token (random string and stuff) will be treated as invalid. One thing though is expired tokens, wherein you have to force call the `onTokenRefresh()` to generate a new one, making the old one expired.

Comment: Problem is the automation tests runs completely on the server. (Automated testing of our backend services).

Comment: @malwatte Big problem then. Registration tokens get generated on the client app side. Not sure if there is an API you can use to generate one from the server side. I'm fairly sure though that it won't be possible with just the server side. Since registration tokens are tied to their client app (not sure what happens under the hood), maybe making use of a device id (depending the type of client app).