# Black hole or dummy devices in Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, performance-testing

I was writing a system which sends push notifications to our Android app users. I was implementing it via [XMPP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref). I wanted to do a load test and get to know how many notifications I can send per second. For which I wanted lot of dummy device IDs as if I use 2-3 device Ids to test, I start to get `DEVICE_MESSAGE_RATE_EXCEEDED` error. So my question is:

1. Is there some way to avoid `DEVICE_MESSAGE_RATE_EXCEEDED` while this testing, can I set this to some higher value for this purpose.
2. Is there some way to get dummy devices Ids, which are not actual users, to whom I can use during my load test. I see an option of [vitual devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/avds), which is paid, is there some other alternative?

I can not send silent notifications to actual users, as I will also start to get production callbacks to my test servers if I use same sender Id as that of production.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there some way to avoid DEVICE_MESSAGE_RATE_EXCEEDED while this testing, can I set this to some higher value for this purpose.*

[`DeviceMessageRateExceeded`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) is encountered when you are sending a lot messages to a specific device (in your case, just three) too fast. If you can, try adding more registration tokens -- this would mean you would need more test devices though.

There is currently no option to change the setting this limit.

> *Is there some way to get dummy devices Ids, which are not actual users, to whom I can use during my load test. I see an option of vitual devices, which is paid, is there some other alternative?*

There isn't. From my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40168892/4625829):

> If by test GCM tokens you mean the registration tokens, it is commonly generated upon app installation. With that said, you don't only receive them when using devices, you can also get one when using an emulator (I for one use it all the time for testing).